# JavaScript simulate escape key keypress for older versions of Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard-events

The following script simulates the escape key being pressed in Gecko/Firefox 31+ (must not contain line breaks):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {bubbles:true, cancelable:true, key:'Esc', char:'Esc', shiftKey:false}));
```

How do I test for support without triggering errors in Gecko/Firefox 30 and older?

How do I simulate the escape key being pressed in Gecko/Firefox 30 and older?

I am testing in Firefox 4.0, Firefox 10 ESR, Firefox 17 ESR, Firefox 24 ESR and Firefox 31 ESR. I don't need support for Internet Explorer.

No frameworks.

Comment: Why do you need to support such old versions of FF? I know that most companies just support the latest two versions.

Comment: @jsve Some projects are larger than others in scale; there are so many scenarios where technology fails (either by itself or people disable updates to be able to use features more important than security updates). Plus these versions are not old, each version only goes back 54 weeks. If you want old browser testing try supporting Internet Explorer 6/7/8.